# How to implement pop -> do something -> push for a queue using goroutines

Tags: concurrency, go, queue, goroutine

I have a queue and I would like to perform the following operations:

- pop the first element
- If the element is even, push element +1

This should go on until the queue is empty; furthermore I want to use multiple goroutines at the same time.

I am able to do for a single goroutine, but as soon as I add a while everything goes wrong, since it appears that too many goroutines are created. Even putting a `else {return}` will not solve the problem. Side question: why not? I get the errors:

```
syntax error: unexpected semicolon or newline before else
syntax error: unexpected }
```

[Link to Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Ane61cV44N)

```
var list = []int{0, 1, 2, 3}

var mutex = &sync.Mutex{}

func pop(out chan int) {
    mutex.Lock()
    element := list[0]
    fmt.Println("element is ", element)
    list = list[1:]
    mutex.Unlock()
    out <- element
}

func push(in chan int) {
    for element := range in {
        if element%2 == 0 {
            mutex.Lock()
            list = append(list, element+1)
            fmt.Println("New list is ", list)
            mutex.Unlock()
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    out := make(chan int)
    fmt.Println("MAIN")

//  for len(list) != 0 {
    go pop(out)
    go push(out)
//}
    time.Sleep(2)
}
```

Comment: Side question's answer: you forgot a semi-colon after `return` and the `else` must be on the same line as the preceding `}`.

Comment: No need for the semicolon, but as @tomwilde said, `else` must be after }, in the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple problems with your code.

- `else` is always on the same line as `if`'s closing brace. Please read [the Spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Semicolons) on this.
- `time.Sleep` takes `time.Duration` as its argument, which is in nanoseconds. If you want to sleep for 2 seconds, use `time.Sleep(2*time.Second)`.
- `for range` in push is not needed.
- Your for `for` just spawns millions of goroutines over and over. Goroutintes are lightweight, but not free. Add some kind of synchronisation mechanism to control how many goroutines you are running.

[Here](http://play.golang.org/p/iG6u-m9pFW) is a slightly better version. It works, even though using `time.Sleep` as a synchronisation mechanism is something you should never do.

Comment: So basically just adding a very small wait time in the for we let some of the routine to finish before generating a huge amount of them? Also are you suggesting to have a global variable that keeps track of how many routines are around?

Comment: @meto Not wait time. An explicit synchronisation mechanism. Something that tells you whether you need more goroutines or not.

Comment: I see. I was wondering why your example works without problems. Is this because the small wait time let some go routines to close rather than continuously spanning new ones?

Comment: @meto Basically, yes. Your code created goroutines so quickly, none of them got to actually do the job. My code works because it creates them more slowly, thus giving the created ones time to do their thing.

Answer (score 4):

A (buffered) channel is a queue, not a stack. Hence pushing and popping don't make sense in that context.

Stacks are LIFO (last in, first out), like travel luggage – you put in last what you need first. Queues are FIFO (first in, first out), like a tube where you push marbles through.

In the context of queues, you're said to enqueue and dequeue elements.

Considering all this, this is what I interpret you'd like to do:

- Create a buffered channel (buffered means that it can hold a number of elements, effectively making it a queue).
- Then fill it up with a bunch of random numbers
- Iterate over it and enqueue again only those that are even, adding 1 to them.

Try to implement this new algorithm.

Comment: Sorry I meant a queue but I used the stack names.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051059/count-display-the-number-of-active-goroutines) (with a new question), even if I don't like the fact that I have to decide a limit for the queue.